# Both implicit wait and webdriver wait are not working

Tags: java

Ii is not at all working with any of the wait statements. It works if I give `Thread.sleep(3000)` and I don't give this statement then it gives me an exception element is not clickable. Can anyone please help me?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./exe/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://demo.actitime.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.name("pwd")).sendKeys("manager");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'TASKS')]"), 1));
    driver.findElement(By.id("logoutLink")).click();
    driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the exception is thrown at:
    driver.findElement(By.id("logoutLink")).click();
when you log into a web page it takes time for the page for the page to verify the information supplied (username and password) is correct if so
you are allowed to log in and therefore the log out button is now clickable... that's why your code works fine when you stop the thread for a while this lets the page log you in and set the button log out clickable